# Rauth doesn't work with requests_cache

Tags: python, python-requests, rauth

Trying to use requests_cache to utilize the monkey patched Session, to maintain a persisted store for responses, Rauth OAuth1Session doesn't seem to play nice.

Assuming keys have been set elsewhere...

```
import requests
import requests_cache
requests_cache.install_cache('test-cache', backend='sqlite', expire_after=300)
from rauth.session import OAuth1Session

session = OAuth1Session(consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumer_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET,
    access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN,
    access_token_secret=ACCESS_SECRET)
r = session.get("http://www.paperbackswap.com/api/v2/index.php", params={"RequestType": "MemberData"});
```

Results in:

```
>  File "run.py", line 5, in <module>
>    from rauth.session import OAuth1Session
>  File "/Users/jasharmon/src/oauth_1.0a_tool/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rauth/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
>    from .service import OAuth1Service, OAuth2Service, OflyService
>  File "/Users/jasharmon/src/oauth_1.0a_tool/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rauth/service.py", line 10, in <module>
>    from rauth.session import OAuth1Session, OAuth2Session, OflySession
>  File "/Users/jasharmon/src/oauth_1.0a_tool/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rauth/session.py", line 28, in <module>
>    class RauthSession(Session):
>  File "/Users/jasharmon/src/oauth_1.0a_tool/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rauth/session.py", line 29, in RauthSession
>    __attrs__ = Session.__attrs__ + ['service']
>AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__attrs__'
```

Comment: Thanks for the formatting help @dave-forgac!

Answer (score 2):

FYI this ended up being because requests_cache used a lambda to monkey patch. Fixed here:
https://github.com/reclosedev/requests-cache/issues/28